# request null value convert to string

Tags: node.js, npm, request

I'm using `request` npm module and when I make request that I passing object with `null` key-value it casting to `''` and it's an error for me.

```
request({
    method: "POST",
    url: "....",
    form: {key: null},
    json: true
}, callbackOnSuccess);
```

Somebody can help me to do the trick?

Comment: I think that if you pass ``undefined`` instead of ``null`` the parameter will not be in the request so you can do something like that ``key : value || undefined``

Comment: But I have array's object and I don't want iterate over array and check all keys..

Comment: Can you provide a code sample with an array ?

Comment: I don't have public API to test what request send it to. But with null value it send ''.

Comment: How do your put your array in the form object of request ? What is the shape of your array ?

Comment: Like this.. `form: [{key: null}]` but it's the same with one object. When I received is `[{key: ''}]`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change values of object properties from `null` to `undefined`, you can use lodash:

```
var newObject = _.mapValues(object, value =>
    value === null ? undefined : value);
```

If you have things like:

```
 [{key: null}]
```

then you may also need to iterate over the array:

```
var newAray = _.map(array, object =>
    _.mapValues(object, value =>
       value === null ? undefined : value));
```

You may also need to remove the keys with `null` values altogether.

You can do it in place:

```
array.forEach(object => Object.keys(object).forEach(key => {
    if (object[key] === null) delete object[key];
}));
```

Or you can create a new array and/or new objects.

Comment: The problem is that `request` use `querystring` so `null` value will be `''`. I'm searching to querystring of nodejs but I don't found nothing :(